# Genesis 22:12 - "..."for I know that you fear God..," what is the possible "interpretation" in consistent with God's sovereign foreknowledge?

Tags: genesis, foreknowledge

Can the interpretation be: God is saying God's foreknowledge is justified?

Or "not caused thee(Abraham?) to know"(Augustine), or "caused others to know(Lange), or "anthropomorphically that thou (Abraham) fearest God, Elohim (Calvin)"? - Pulpit Comm.)

Or yet could there be another interpretation of the text revealing All-knowing God's motive?

Text Gen. 22:12:

ESV -He said, “Do not lay your hand on the boy or do anything to him, **for now I know that you fear God**, seeing you have not withheld your son, your only son, from me.”

YLT - and He saith, 'Put not forth thine hand unto the youth, nor do anything to him, **for now I have known that thou art fearing God**, and hast not withheld thy son, thine only one, from Me.'

Comment: A [related](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/39719) question.

Comment: As with the vast hordes of such questions stored in the archives of the website (many obscured from most readers as they are closed) this is an attempt to peer beyond the word of scripture and to peer into the eternal being of the eternal God. Instead of pondering some obscure 'interpretation' why not just receive (the way a child receives) what is on the page -  _... for now I know that thou fearest God_ [KJV]. Robert Young was scrupulous about Hebrew tenses and insists on a literal (but not idiomatic) presentation of the tense. But the meaning is quite clear to the unclouded judgment.

Comment: @Nigel seems you overreacting and jumps to a conclusion not knowing what the question is for. There are various interpretations from many big names as my citations. Yet there could still be a better interpretation that reveals what "All-knowing God's purpose of testing Abraham.

Comment: @Nigel I added more to my question, perhaps this will make the question clearer.

Comment: @Nigel please note, my question says "what is the possible interpretation in consistent with God's sovereign foreknowledge?"

Comment: Explain why  "closed?

Comment: I have voted to re-open, hoping the Moderators will put it into Hermeneutics, as that seems the appropriate section. If they do not, can you post a fresh question on this in Hermeneutics?

Comment: @Anne -Thanks! I will wait further for a convincing answer. Meantime, I welcome your posting in Hermeneutics.

Comment: @Anne - I want all concerned parties to know, I wholeheartedly adhere to the doctrine of the eternal, infinite omniscience of God. My aim for the posting is to bring us to better understand, even closer to the intended purpose of God for our benefits, if possible. Those comments cited were for a stepping tone with no hostile intentions. I welcome suggestions for making it a better/clear posting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the interpretation is to show that, "God's foreknowledge is justified." The following is from John Gill who is quoting someone else.

Psalm 1:6; Saadiah Gaon (i) interprets it, "I have made known", that is, to others; God by trying Abraham made it manifest to others, to all the world, to all that should hear of or read this account of things, that he was a man that feared God, loved him, believed in him, and obeyed him, of which this instance is a full and convincing proof:"

Or to put it another way, "The sacrifice was already accomplished in Abraham's heart." As I'm typing this I thought of what Jesus said at John 21:15-17. He ask Peter if he loved Him three times. Do you think that Jesus knew this already?

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48014/is-there-a-causal-connection-between-the-denial-of-peter-and-christs-question/48116#48116

Comment: This text is only one of other several  verses in the Scripture that Hermeneutic ( nor Theology, nor Logic) cannot answer, but only good Biblical Theology can. It is my purpose of the posting the question to seek the best answer from the perspective of God's Sovereign Foreknowledge.
 Ps 1:6 comment is in my question 2nd paragraph.   On Jn 21:15-17, I have posted an answer: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48014/is-there-a-causal-connection-between-the-denial-of-peter-and-christs-question/48116#48116

Comment: Explain why closed.